# Acessar atributo FK no entity Framewokr

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Eu tenho a classe `Cliente` que possui um `IList<Produto>` e a classe de `produto` possui um `ClienteId` (que é a FK) e um atributo `Cliente Cliente { get; set; }`. Como acessar o atributo `Nome` de `Cliente` em produto?

```
public class Cliente 
{
  ....
  public string Nome {get;set;}

  public IList<Produto> Produtos {get;set;}
}

public class Produto
{
  ....
  public int ClienteId {get;set;}

  public Cliente Cliente{get;set;}
}
```

OBS: todos os campos estão mapeados, e estão trazendo dados.

Comment: Não compreendi se tem algo a mais ou sua dúvida é mais simples do que imagino. Mas, se todos os dados estão sendo preenchidos, basta usar `produto.Cliente.Name`, sendo `produto` a instância da classe `Produto`. Há também um 'typo' nas suas classes, está referenciando a classe `Produto` mas o nome da classe é `Produtos`.

Comment: eu queria acessar a propriedade `Nome` de `Cliente` em `Produto`,
eu tentei dessa forma `Produto.cliente.Nome` e `ProdutoClienteNome`, e não da certo.

Comment: Tentou acessar as propriedades via debug? Ocorre algum erro ao tentar acessar? O intellisense informa o nome das propriedades?

Comment: @Vinicius, tente alterar a propriedade Cliente como virtual, para permitir que o Entity faça o Lazy loading.

Comment: @JuniorPorfirio deu certo alterar para virtual